# Clustering groups if items in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Apologies if this question has already been answered. I've been combing through all of the documentation for various clustering algorithms in R, and I haven't found one that quite matches what I'm trying to do.

Long story short, I have a list of items in a dataset. These items are items that are put up during a auction process. Thus, you may see the same item in different auction processes over time. What I'm trying to do is to create a measure to analyze the amount of "clustering" between the items. That is, to see whether certain items are consistently being grouped together in an auction process time and time again.

Take this simple example:

(ITEM, AUCTION PROCESS)
(A, 1)
(B, 1)
(A, 2)
(A, 3)
(B, 4)
(C, 4)
(C, 5)
(B, 6)
(D, 6)
(A, 7)
(B, 8)
(C, 8)
(A, 9)
(D, 10)
(E, 11)

So one can see that item B is very connected to most of the other items since it shares an auction process with most of them. Moreover, items B and C are grouped in many of the same auction process. Whereas item A is only connected to items C and D through B, and is not connected to E at all.

Is there a package in R that can easily do this type of clustering? Two things to note: the auction process is a string variable in my dataset, and the number of items is very large (~10,000 or so).

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Have you tried `kmeans` in base R? You should think about converting your data to a data frame. Also, check out igraph - you might want to represent this as a network where each node is an item, belonging to a different group (auction process)

Comment: Check out `kmeans {stats}` and `hclust {stats}` these are the go to methods to start a clustering analysis. Package called **caret** [link](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) has a lot more machine learning options implemented. You should also post a more reproducible example to get more detailed help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In terms of kmeans clustering, I need to set a predetermined value of k, correct? Is there a way to be agnostic about this, and to allow the program to determine the optimal numbers of clusters that the items are group into?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than clustering, you appear to be looking for

**frequent itemset mining**

I.e. combinations of products ("items") that appear in the same auctions ("transactions")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item <- c('A','B','A','A','B','C','C','B','D','A','B','C','A','D','E')
item<-as.numeric(factor(item))
auctionProc <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,10,11)
df <- data.frame(item, auctionProc)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(df$auctionProc,
           df$item)) + 
  xlab("Auction Process") + ylab('Item') + 
  ggtitle('Auction Process vs Item Clustering') +
  geom_point()

cluster <- kmeans(df[, 1:2], 3, nstart = 20)
cluster$cluster <- as.factor(cluster$cluster)

ggplot(df, aes(df$auctionProc,
           df$item, 
           color = cluster$cluster)) + 
  xlab("Auction Process") + ylab('Item') + 
  ggtitle('Auction Process vs Item Clustering') +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Cluster Index") + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]
[image]